# Silverlight player that supports "seeking" to a random position in the stream

Tags: silverlight, video, video-streaming

Does anyone know of a Silverlight Video player that permits "seeking" to a particular offset of the stream without having to download the whole thing?

I'm a bit new to this Silverlight gig, so will appreciate anything you can point me to to get me up to speed.

Answer (score 1):

I come from a flash background, but I think this may apply to silverlight too.

Generally speaking, It's not the player that determines whether you can jump to a point in video but how the video is delivered.

Generally speaking - If you are downloading the video progressively over http, you will have to wait until the section of the video you want to skip to has been downloaded before you can jump to it. This is not always the case, YouTube, for example serve their content progressively. Also, this guy came up with another solution - http://www.flashcomguru.com/index.cfm/2005/11/2/Streaming-flv-video-via-PHP-take-two You may be able to find a similar workaround using dot net rather than php.

An easier way to achieve your goal, although not as cheap, would be to use a streaming server. You can use specific severs to allow actual video **streaming**, where you will be able to  jump to various points in the video. I've found wowza quite good - http://www.wowzamedia.com/ Or to use a service like limelight or streamzilla. However they can be very very expensive.